# Get value of PeopleEditor control field in a string

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, visual-web-part, people-picker, ssom

How can I retrieve value of `SharePoint:PeopleEditor` control in a string programmatically in Server Side Object Model (C#)?

Answer (score 1):

Sample ASP control:

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor runat="server" ID="spOwner" />
```

Sample C# code for update item based on this control:

```
string[] users= spOwner.CommaSeparatedAccounts.Split(',');
SPFieldUserValueCollection usersSPList = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();
foreach (string user in users)
{
  try
  {
    web.EnsureUser(user);
    SPUser usersSP = web.SiteUsers[user];
    SPFieldUserValue usersSPValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, usersSP.ID, usersSP.LoginName);
    usersSPList.Add(usersSPValue);
  }
  catch (SPException)
  {
    // your code
  }
}
itemList[fieldOwner.Id] = usersSPList;
itemList.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your control is multi selection allowed. `peUser` is your `SharePoint:PeopleEditor` control.

Below code will do the work

```
           string selectedUser = String.Empty;
           if (peUser.IsValid)
            {
                for (int index = 0; index <= peUser.ResolvedEntities.Count - 1; ++index)
                {
                    PickerEntity entity = (PickerEntity)peUser.ResolvedEntities[index];
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedUser))
                        selectedUser += entity.Key;
                    else
                        selectedUser += ";" + entity.Key;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Gaurrav, I appreciate your response but I am looking for single select value bcoz I have disabled multi-select and that is my requirement.

Comment: It will work in both case